# opencms blog list shows blog entries of Demo-site

Tags: blogs, opencms

wanted to create blog in opencms. I followed Demo-site, created blog i had also created blog entries, but in blog list  i am getting blog entries of demo site . Please throw some light regarding this

Answer (score 0):

If you have your own subsitemap, you have to define (in your .config file, that the blog entries of this subsite should be stored in the .content folder of this subsite.
Don't forget to define a detail page for this subsitemap.

Comment: i am not using subsitemap, under main site only  i created blog folder and added detail page for main site in config file